npx not using right version of npm
When using an npx command such as (npx shadcn@latest add radio-group). The following error occurs :
Command failed with exit code 1: npm install @radix-ui/react-radio-group
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v20.15.0

This seems to be caused by the fact that a wrong version of npm is being used (i'm using nvm). I separately have to call the referred npm command (npm install @radix-ui/react-radio-group which works fine when called directly, just not through npx). Is it possible to specify an npm version in npx commands (i have tried the npm exec alternative which does not work as well).

The npx command comes together with the npm command. Changing the npm version with nvm will change it for npx as well.
